# Pagina en blanco en ReportViewer

Tags: c#, windows-forms, reportviewer

Resulta que cree un reporte en ReportViewer con datos de la base de datos en sql server y lo genero como hoja A4 en horizontal el, tema es que cuando pongo la vista previa me genera dos hojas una con los datos y otra en blanco, ya intente quitando los margenes achicando lo mas posible la tabla de datos pero no resulta ninguna la solución, también puse en false la opción "Permitir aumentar tamaño" de cada celda y en los controles también igual.
Este es el reporte.
[image: Estos son los datos del reporte con sus margenes, etc.]

Y así sale en la vista previa cuando genero los datos para el reporte 
[image: Pagina 1]

[Pagina 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apL8I.png)

[image: Pagina 2]

Por favor si alguien me pueda dar una mano le agradecería mucho,
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que código de tamaño de hoja le estas asignando desde la carga de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logre Solucionarlo de esta forma, resulta que me fui a propiedades del reporte y en la propiedad "ConsumeContainer" estaba en false y lo puse en true provee y resulto que era eso, yo supongo que por cada columna de datos que se creaba generaba un espacio o algo así, pero se soluciono

[image: ConsumeContainer]

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente es porque el ancho es demasiado largo, específicamente es porque ancho del `body` mas los márgenes izquierdo y derecho deben se menor al ancho del `page size` del reporte, ya que si te pasas aunque sea por un `1px` te va a generar la hoja en blanco.

Asegúrate de estas dimensiones, viendo la regla en diseño o verificando en la ventana propiedades de ancho del `body` y las dimensiones de los márgenes.

---

Adicional

Si tienes problemas con los tamaños de los controles, te recomendaría ampliar el ancho según tus necesidades, aumentes los tamaños en el `page size` del reporte y verifiques que el `interactive size` tenga las dimensiones de la hoja que vas a trabajar.

Por ejemplo:

Tus columnas y el reporte tienen un ancho total de 9in *(pulgadas)* y los margenes están en 0.5 in; lo que hace que tu reporte de ancho tenga 10in y es necesario imprimirlo en una hoja carta (8.5x11)in en vertical, entonces en el `page size` pones:

```
width = 10in
```

El alto por una regla  de tres determinas la proporcionalidad:

```
height = 10 x 11 / 8.5 = 12.94
```

y te aseguras que el `interactive size` tenga las dimensiones correctas, esto hará que la impresión se ajuste al tamaño de la hoja, sin que estés haciendo pequeñas las celdas y modificando las fuentes.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, J Fuentes y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas mas acerca de esta comunidad.  Saludos